# remove a character from the end of a text string only if it is there in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of file names in excel I need to Match with another list. Some of the file names contain extra characters that need to be removed first though. I have a formula that will remove special characters and spaces from the file names;

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($E8,"_",""),"-",""),".","")," ","")

But some of the file names contain an extra 1 at the end I need to remove, please see example;

- 2AALNOR120114
- DCA CDE 12-01-14
- OPASDOCS120114
- TWASCE120214**1**
- TWASCE120314**1**
- STCSRA1201**20**14**1**
- STCSRA1202**20**14**1**

If anyone could give me a Formula solution that strips out the above special characters and the 1 at the end of the filename that would be great.

Bonus credit if you can also strip out the 20 from the STC files as well to output as STCSRA120114 instead of STCSRA12012014

Edit: For clarification, final result would ideally look like this;

- 2AALNOR120114
- DCACDE120114
- OPASDOCS120114
- TWASCE120214
- TWASCE120314
- STCSRA120114
- STCSRA120214

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="1",1,0))
```

(Replace the first two instances of `A1` above with a suitable version of your SUBSTITUTE formula, and the last with `E8`).

With substitution:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E8,"_",""),"-",""),".","")," ",""),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E8,"_",""),"-",""),".","")," ",""))-IF(RIGHT(E8,1)="1",1,0))
```

A sightly shorter version of the `A1` one:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-(RIGHT(A1)="1"))
```

Comment: Your formula works on it's own but I'm having trouble combining it with the existing formula. Can it be combined as one formula?

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you so much!The STC issue is small and I can work around it but your formula helps me immensely. Thanks again!